# Функция, возвращающая значения разных типов

Tags: функции, типы-данных, rust

Как можно написать функцию, которая при определенных условиях возвращает значения разных типов?

Например:

```
fn function(type_var:&str) {
   if type_var == "i32" {
      return 50i32;
   } else if type_var == "f64" {
      return 50.0;
   } else {
      return '50';
   }
```

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно? Всякий раз когда я слышу, что функция в PHP возвращает объект такого-то типа/класса или `false` - хочется сжечь её (а, возможно, и её разработчиков) на месте.

Comment: Например для чтения строки. Одна функция `read()`, а возвращаемое значение зависит от типа переменной, которой это значение присваивается. Конечно лучше написать несколько отдельных функций для каждого типа, но интересно, как сделать это только с одной.

Comment: Я про `rust` первый раз слышу - возможно, там всё по-своему. Но с точки зрения программирования как такового _несколько методов_ для меня звучит лучше. Либо использование одного метода, возвращающего фиксированный тип, с последующим преобразованием в нужный тип вне функции при присваивании или внутри самого объекта.

Comment: Если нужна функция, возвращающая разный тип в зависимости от способа вызова, то для этого есть переметрический полиморфизм. Для функции типа read будет что-то вроде `fn read<T: FromStr, R: Read>(reader: R) -> T { let mut buf = String::new(); reader.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap(); buf.parse::<T>().unwrap() }` (без обработки ошибок, если чтение или парсинг прочитанной строки зафейлиться — будет паника).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Rust строгая типизация, поэтому тип возвращаемого значения должен быть какой-то один. Тем не менее, можно создать тип-перечисление с различными типами вложенных значений в вариантах:

```
enum ParsedValue {
    Int32(i32),
    Float(f64),
    String(String)
}
```

(последний вариант типа `String` с динамическим выделением и копированием строки, чтобы не отвлекаться на параметры времени жизни; если нужен пример не-аллоцирующей функции, могу развить).

Функция в примере будет выглядеть так:

```
fn function(type_var: &str) -> ParsedValue {
    if type_var == "i32" {
        ParsedValue::Int32(50)
    } else if type_var == "f64" {
        ParsedValue::Float(50.0)
    } else {
        ParsedValue::String(String::from("50"))
    }
}
```

По значению `ParsedValue` все равно придется делать что-нибудь вроде `match`, чтобы деструктурировать значение варианта, но этот `match` обязан быть исчерпывающим.